# How was this deviance formula for Cox Proportional Hazard derived?

Tags: survival, cox-model, deviance

The gbm package in R documents the following deviance formula for CoxPH models

http://gradientboostedmodels.googlecode.com/git/gbm/inst/doc/gbm.pdf

$-2 \sum w_i \delta_i (f(x_i) - \log(R_i / w_i)$, where $w_i$ is a weight for the observation, $\delta_i$ is the right censor indicator and $R_i = \sum_{j=1}^N 1(t_j >= t_i) e^{f(x_i)}$ is the total hazard of the risk set

However this formula does not seem to agree with the author's implementation.

https://github.com/harrysouthworth/gbm/issues/22

I'm wondering how this was derived so I can figure out if there is a bug in the implementation or if there is a mistake with the way the formula was written